# How to fetch images dynamic from nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Api image return to dynamic with req params

I have currently use

```
app.use('/api/uploads', checkAuth, express.static('uploads/report/', { fallthrough: false }));
```

I have set dynamic upload path like

request url  = api/uploads/report/abc.png

set automatic path Like

```
app.use('/api/uploads', checkAuth, (req) => express.static('uploads/'+req.UserData.GroupName+'/report/', { fallthrough: false }));
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the issue? Are you unable to get the image? What path is it creating?

Comment: @mehta-rohan  not any error return api call time out

Comment: @apoorva-chikara not any response return api call time out

Comment: check permission of uploads/report/ folder

Comment: There are two things 1) check if the file exist 2) check if the path is correct. When you make the request you should check the path.

Comment: file is exist and all dir permission proper